How to import and migrate the checked checkbox in Oracle APEX
Hi I am using the Oracle APEX to build an application to register the records in my company.
The aim of the app is to register the issues when spotted during sales.
We have the checkbox that when checked, works as YES, when not checked, it is set as N/A.
Next to the entry, I have edit / view and duplicated buttons. We clicking on EDIT, the checkbox selection is there and it can be modified. When I click 'duplicate', I am being redirected to the EDIT page but all the fields are filled in based on copied records, except for what was set in the checkbox.
While looking at the session details, I can see the Y value is being inserted alothough the checkbox appears to be 'not checked'
Any idea how this can be solved?
Thank you

Does checkbox column exist in the underlying table? If so, which value does it contain (i.e. can it be "mapped" to what you use in Apex application)? If not, shouldn't it be added?

What I noticed is that the default values for checkbox (apex defaults) are yes and no. When the checkbox is ticked, the record in the database gets saved as Y or N and I suspect this could be the issue.

Based on what you commented, you could create list of values as a SQL query which contains two values:

display, which will then be YES and N/A
return, which will be Y and N


select 'YES' as d, 'Y' as r from dual union all
select 'N/A' as d, 'N' as r from dual

